# Splitting a single column into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, split

I have a table that's stored in a single column of a data frame. I want to convert that single column into a data frame with the original column names.

```
> head(Table)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  table                                                          
  <chr>                                                          
1 "Characteristic                  Urban      Rural        Total"
2 "_________________________________________________"            
3 "Electricity"                                                  
4 "  Yes                        99.8   94.4     98.9"            
5 "  No                           0.2    5.6      1.1"           
6 "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0"
```

I want to convert this into a data frame with the same columns,
Characteristic, Urban, Rural, Total.

The only time the integers occur are in the last 3 columns. I'm not sure if I can use that to separate the columns?

```
> dput(Table)
structure(list(table = c("Characteristic                  Urban      Rural        Total", 
"_________________________________________________", "Electricity", 
"  Yes                        99.8   94.4     98.9", "  No                           0.2    5.6      1.1", 
"Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", "Source of drinking water", 
"  Piped into residence       97.1   81.4     94.4", "  Public tap                   0.0    0.3      0.1", 
"  Well in residence            1.1    3.7      1.6", "  Public well                  0.0    0.4      0.1", 
"  Spring                       0.0    2.3      0.4", "  Rainwater                    0.3    0.6      0.3", 
"  Tanker truck                 1.0  10.6       2.7", "  Bottled water                0.3    0.1      0.3", 
"  Other                        0.1    0.5      0.2", "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", 
"Time to water source", " (in minutes)", "  <15 minutes                99.9   97.5     99.5", 
"Type of salt used", " for cooking", "  Salt not used                0.1    0.1      0.1", 
"  Packaged salt, iodized     95.8   91.3     95.0", "  Packaged salt, noniodized    3.8    8.4      4.6", 
"  Other                        0.2    0.2      0.2", "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", 
"Sanitation facility", "  Own flush toilet           94.0   70.8     90.1", 
"  Shared flush toilet          1.6    2.4      1.8", "  Traditional pit toilet       4.2  24.0       7.5", 
"  No facility                  0.1    2.8      0.6", "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", 
"Type of sewage system", "  Public network             70.5     4.4    59.2", 
"  Dug hole                   29.3   92.4     40.1", "  No sewage                    0.1    3.1      0.6", 
"  Missing                      0.1    0.0      0.1", "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", 
"Main floor material", "  Earth/sand                   0.1    1.4      0.3", 
"  Wood planks                  0.0    0.1      0.0", "  Vinyl/asphalt strips         0.6    0.3      0.5", 
"  Ceramic tiles              86.2   61.8     82.1", "  Cement                     13.1   36.3     17.0", 
"Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", "Persons per sleeping room", 
"  1-2                        50.4   40.6     48.7", "  3-4                        39.1   41.8     39.5", 
"  5-6                          8.4  13.0       9.2", "  7+                           2.1    4.7      2.5", 
"  Missing/Don't know           0.1    0.0      0.1", "Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0", 
"Mean                           3.0    3.4      3.0", "Number of households        6,086  1,249    7,335", 
"", "", "", "", "                             14", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share a `dput()` of your data instead? How exactly did this odd, single-column data.frame get created? It's often easier to fix the problem at the source rather than try to fix it later in the pipeline.

Comment: @MrFlick Its a table from a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(table != "_________________________________________________" ) %>% 
  mutate(table = str_trim(table)) %>% 
  separate(table, sep = "\\s+(?=\\d+)", 
     into = c("Characteristic", "Urban", "Rural", "Total"), fill = "right") %>% 
  filter(Characteristic != "") %>% 
  slice(-1) 

#> # A tibble: 54 × 4
#>    Characteristic           Urban Rural Total
#>    <chr>                    <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Electricity              <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#>  2 Yes                      99.8  94.4  98.9 
#>  3 No                       0.2   5.6   1.1  
#>  4 Total                    100.0 100.0 100.0
#>  5 Source of drinking water <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#>  6 Piped into residence     97.1  81.4  94.4 
#>  7 Public tap               0.0   0.3   0.1  
#>  8 Well in residence        1.1   3.7   1.6  
#>  9 Public well              0.0   0.4   0.1  
#> 10 Spring                   0.0   2.3   0.4  
#> # … with 44 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit`.

```
tmp <- lapply(strsplit(dat$V2, '\\s+')[c(1, 4:6)], \(x) x[x != ''])
(r <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, tmp[-1]), tmp[[1]]) |> 
  type.convert(as.is=T))
#   Characteristic Urban Rural Total
# 1            Yes  99.8  94.4  98.9
# 2             No   0.2   5.6   1.1
# 3          Total 100.0 100.0 100.0
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V2 = c("Characteristic                  Urban      Rural        Total", 
"_________________________________________________", "Electricity", 
"  Yes                        99.8   94.4     98.9", "  No                           0.2    5.6      1.1", 
"Total                       100.0  100.0    100.0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I put the dput() into the original post, my larger Table doesn't seem to work with this.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Your dput is incomplete! Please always test dput when posting.